# converting varchar to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

I have 2 fields date_issued and time_issued as below

```
date_issued       time_issued
1031              225225 (22 hrs 52 mins 25 secs)
```

I need to convert that varchar value to datetime as dd-mm-yy h:m:s

I tried following

```
select CONVERT(datetime, date_issued+time_issued ,120) as ttt from tbl
```

but is showing following error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming year is 2012:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2012' + LEFT(date_issued, 2) + RIGHT(date_issued, 2) + ' ' + LEFT(time_issued, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(time_issued, 3, 2) + ':' + right(time_issued, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all.

U have an obvious error. If those columns are numbers (not strings) you are adding them up and that is plainly wrong.

Second, if those are strings, you are missing a year in date area and you are missing : in time area.
Third, you need to add a ' ' between those 2.

in my example

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'20091231 12:12:12') FROM DUAL
```

i get

```
2009-12-31 12:12:12.000
```

P.S. Yes, i have DUAL in SQL server, this wasn't ran in Oracle.

Comment: This is not exactly he wanted

Comment: well, how about i write him exact code so he doesn't need to think. date_issued + 2012 + ' ' + substring(time_issued, 0, 2) + ':' +substring(time_issued, 2, 2) + ':' + substring(time_issued, 4, 2). If you think it will help him learn something and not copy paste?

Comment: well on that case...you are right. Idea is to just show the way but not the full code

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, you can remove `REPLICATE` if the data includes leading zeros, else it is needed for padding to discriminate the date parts.

```
select
    cast ( 
        stuff(replicate('0', 4 - len(date_issued)) + date_issued, 3, 0, '/') + '/2012'
        + ' ' +
        stuff(stuff(replicate('0', 6 - len(time_issued)) + time_issued, 3, 0, ':'), 6 ,0 ,':')
    as datetime)
```